# Get values from Record-edit-form onload LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-web-components

I have this below **lightning-record-edit-form**. I want to get the value from **Name** **lightning-input-field** so that i can do some manipulation at javascript end.

Currenlty i am getting null on load of the form.

How to get the value.

HTML

```
<lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name="Test__c" onload={handleOnLoad}>
<lightning-input-field variant="label-stacked" class="name" field-name="Name"></lightning-input-field>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

JS -

```
  handleOnLoad() {
        let name= this.template.querySelector('.name');
        alert(name);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
handleOnLoad() {
    let name = this.template.querySelector('.name').value;
    alert(name);
}
```

This will work.

**BUT above approach is not good. You can get all the values based on recordId as below**

```
handleOnLoad(event) {
    var record = event.detail.records;
    var fields = record[this.recordId].fields; // record['0010K000026Y******'].fields;
    const accName = fields.Name.value;      
    alert(accName);
    //const myfieldVal = fields.myfield__c.value;
    //alert(myfieldVal);
}
```

Comment: Hi @salesforcesas .. it worked for inputfield perfectly.. but for lightning-output-field it is giving "undefined" error. is there any workaround..

Comment: pls mark as accepted if it solved

Comment: Apologies.. for tht

Comment: Hi @salesforce-sas, I have tried the same as follows

````var recordsMap = event.detail.records;
var record = recordsMap[this.recordId];````

but at line 2, nothing is found with that ID and returning undefined.
Help me where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: it seems there is a issue  console.log("OnLoadData-", JSON.stringify(event.detail.records)); is returning undefined.